# What is the charater code of the arrow used in location bar/breadcrumb bar of Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, special-characters

I want to know the character code of the arrows that used in Windows 7's Explorer as below screenshot - the ones that are marked red.

(Reason: I want to add a button like that in my WPF application)

Please share if you know the character codes in Word.

[image]

**Edit**

Addition to `eidylon` answer here is the details
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as Ignacio said, those are images specified in your visual style. Depending on the visual style you're using they actually can look quite different. That said, the double-chevron at the beginning can be represented with <kbd>ALT</kbd>**+(174)** and the corresponding right-double-chevron is <kbd>ALT</kbd>**+(175)**. You can get some *SIMILAR* arrows to the solid ones by running charmap (assuming you're on Windows), and set **Group By** to "Unicode Subrange". In the group by box that pops up select "Block Elements and Geometric Shapes". You can find arrows for all four cardinal directions in there. If you click on one it will show you the unicode in the statusbar of the charmap window.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of characters in Unicode that come close, but the truth is that they're probably just images being shown in a custom control, and the only way to do this is to draw them yourself in the client area of the control in the paint method.

Answer (score 1):

Also refer to @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams' answer.

From a more traditional perspective, the font Marlett contains most of the arrows & shapes used in old style windows controls (including the solid arrows you asked).

The double arrow can easily be found in unicode fonts. Please try to run "Character Map".